# Jungledisk Desktop not showing a window after 1st run

Tags: 11.04, unity

I am using Jungledisk Desktop to backup my files, but on Ubuntu 11.04 the main application window is not showing after the 1st run.

When I delete all `.jungledisk*` files in my home directory the main application window is showing, but when I start the application the next time, no window is showing. Only notification toasts are displayed on the top right.

I already added `junglediskdesktop` to my systray whitelist, but that doesn't help.

What can I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to restart my Ubuntu to enable the systray settings. I allowed `all` applications, and now I have `truecrypt` and `junglediskdesktop` in the tray. Finally. :-)

I used `dconf-editor` to set this. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I finally got it working by adding jungledisk to the systray whitelist.  Adding junglediskdesktop doesn't work.